# This could be because the page is unavailable or blocked by robots.txt

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt

My `robots.txt` file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

When I test my `WordPress site` at `google mobile-friendly`, I got this error:

> Page cannot be reached
>
> This could be because the page is unavailable or blocked by robots.txt

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be compatible to all robots, if one wants to allow single files inside an otherwise disallowed directory, it is necessary to place the Allow directive(s) first, followed by the Disallow.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive

Try this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```